# What are the necessary requirements for proving NP is closed under complement?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, np-complete, np-hard, np

I've had the following question on a test and I answered: 'False', my answer was incorrect and I'm trying to understand why.

$VC = \{<G,k> |\ G =$ undirected graph with a vertex cover of size $k\}$

$IS = \{<G,k>|\ G =$ undirected graph with an independent set of size $k\}$

**Ture or False:**

**Assuming there exists a language $A$ such that:
$
(VC≤_P A) \land (\overline{A} ≤_P IS)
$
then NP is closed under complement**

When trying to prove it is true I tried to use the following theorem:

> $L\in NPComplete \land L\in coNP →  =  → NP$ is closed
> under complement

My attempt:

We know both VC and IS are NPComplete problems,
which implies from the reductions that:

$A \in \text{NP-Hard}$ and $\overline{A}\in NP$

the only thing missing is $A\in NP$ for satisfying the condition: $A\in NPComplete \land A\in coNP$ and reaching the conclusion: $NP=coNP$

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

ok apparently $\overline{IS}$ is also $NPComplete$ which means
$A \in NP$   and we already know from the reduction that
$A\in \text{NP-Hard}$ which mean $A\in NPComplete$

we also know that $\overline{A}\in NP$

$→A\in NPComplete \land A\in coNP → NP=coNP →$ NP is closed under complement